# CoreData in main thread is common?

Tags: core-data

I worked with coreData some times, and I never search anything about this until import a lot of information.

CoreData by default using mainThread to create, update, delete and querying entities?

If yes, is a common scenario or is better use another thread to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is common to use CoreData from the main thread. But it depends on your application's needs. If your application has some heavy CoreData work or needs to load the data in the background in order to make the UI more responsive, you can do it with multithreading but you will need to follow apple's guidelines.

You can find the apple's guide for Concurrency in NSManagedObjectContext [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW39).